# Mathematical operator for rounding the numbers up with lots of decimal places

Tags: sql, postgresql, math, rounding

I have a number: **0.01744649** and I need to round it from behind. I would like to get a result: **0.018**

P.S.
I've tried all the possibilities of documentation: [enter link description here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-math.html) - every time I get a different result but not this what I want.

Comment: What does "round it from behind" mean?

Comment: Did you try `round(42.4382, 3)` it will give you `42.438`

Comment: Yes, when i use: 
`SELECT round(0.01744649, 3)` 
then I get 0.017 but i need 0.018

Answer (score 3):

Use [ceil](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/functions-math.html):

```
SELECT ceil(0.01744649 * 1000) / 1000
```

---

If you need to round one digit at a time, like this: `0.01744649` -> `0.0174465` -> `0.017447` -> `0.01745` -> `0.0175` -> `0.018`, here's the function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.rounding(_value numeric, _precision int)
  RETURNS numeric AS
$BODY$
DECLARE
    tmp_val numeric;
    i   integer;
BEGIN
    tmp_val = _value;

    i = 10;
    WHILE i >= _precision LOOP
        tmp_val = round(tmp_val, i);
        i = i - 1;
    END LOOP;

    RETURN tmp_val;
END;
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
  COST 100;
```

Usage:

```
SELECT public.rounding(0.01744649, 3);
0.018

SELECT public.rounding(0.01744444, 3);
0.017
```

Comment: It will give `0.017`, not `0.018` like in question is

Comment: ghp=# SELECT ceil(0.01744649 * 1000) / 1000
ghp-# ;
        ?column?        
------------------------
 0.01800000000000000000
(1 row)

Comment: @AndreiSuvorkov It _will_ give 0.018.

Comment: No it won't, it gives 0.018

Comment: Yes, you are right. Didn't pay attention to example. It was with negative numbers

Comment: Thanks friend! That's what it was about! You saved me!

Comment: I don't think so, because "SELECT ceil(0.01744444 * 1000) / 1000;"  returns 0.018 also.

Comment: It is a _ceiling_ function so it will round up no matter what further decimal digit is (in opposite, the _floor_ function will round down). I think you need to be more precise in describing your problem.

Comment: @DuGi Do you mean rounding one digit at a time, like this: 0.01744649 -> 0.0174465 -> 0.017447 -> 0.01745 -> 0.0175 -> 0.018? You would need to make your own function to do that.

Comment: I am writing a recursive function to do your bidding. Almost there (I hope).

Comment: @Adam it's perfect, now i don't need, I did something else becouse I had no time
but thank you very much, I will need it for the future :)

Answer (score 1):

You just need to add 5/10000 before rounding to 3 decimals.

```
select round(0.01744649+0.0005,3);

 round 
-------
 0.018
(1 row)
```

Comment: I do not want to add another number.

Comment: Then perhaps subtract -0.0005 ?   It is a novel technique, this "rounding from behind".   Where is it used?

Comment: I create a system for the integration of settlements between cryptocurrency exchanges. Unfortunately, it happens that from one stock exchange the funds go out with a few decimal places after the decimal point and the second stock exchange goes rounded. I am looking for the best solution for correlation of such cases.

Answer (score 1):

```
create or replace function dugi_round (
  p_fl numeric,
  p_pr int,
  p_depth int default 0
  ) returns numeric language plpgsql as $$
declare n_fl numeric;
begin
  n_fl := p_fl * 10.0;
  -- raise notice 'we have now %, %',n_fl,p_pr;
  if floor(n_fl) < n_fl then
     -- raise notice 'remaining diff % - % = %',
     --              n_fl, floor(n_fl), n_fl - floor(n_fl);
     n_fl := dugi_round(n_fl, p_pr, p_depth + 1);
  end if;
  if (p_depth > p_pr) then
    n_fl := round(n_fl / 10);
  else
    n_fl := round(n_fl / 10, p_pr);
  end if;
  -- raise notice 'returning %, %', n_fl, p_pr;
  return n_fl;
end;
$$
;


ghp=# select dugi_round(0.01744649, 3);
 dugi_round
------------
      0.018
(1 row)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to round it to the 3rd decimal, try to multiply it by 1000, ceil it and divide it by 1000 again. That should produce the result you're expecting.

Comment: He's not trying to round as in any of the rounding systems known to wikipedia.

Comment: @GerardH.Pille By the accepted answer I can guess you're wrong.

Comment: Can you, Ahmed?  But you guessed wrong.  You should be more critical, do not believe everything you hear or read.

Comment: Reading the other answers again I'll have to agree that it was me who was wrong, sorry about that, Gerard :)

Comment: No worries, I'm a snowflake.